# integrating pouchdb using ionic2/angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

i am getting error while importing pouchdb in ionic2(installed through npm)

```
 Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'pouchdb'.
```

importing modules in the following way,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

Also tried in the following way using 'require',

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
```

But giving the following error

```
can not find name 'require'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pouchdb` as shown below :

```
declare function require(a)

var PouchDB = require("pouchdb")
```

Comment: Thanks @ranakrunal9, it is working fine. But how can i see the stored data(pochdb)  in chrome browser.

Comment: You can follow pouchdb tutorial like http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/ or http://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/

Comment: @vishnu Press f12 then go to the Application tab where you can see PouchDB options.click on it and see all the records.